# Route host traffic through WSL

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL2 instead of a kali vm to do some hacktheboxes. To do this, I use openvpn in the kali machine. The problem is that I want my windows machine to also route through the vpn. Is there a way to do this?

Side note: would activating the vpn on the host route wsl traffic through that? If so, that may be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out activating the VPN on the host OS will provide access to that network to the WSL guest as well.